# Proving 2 sets are equivalent (Symmetric difference)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to determine whether this pair of sets:
$A\Delta(B\cap C); (A\Delta B) \cap (A \Delta C)$
Is equivalent/One is subset of the other/neither.
Any hint on how to approach this? I've tried to use logical biconditions to get from one to the other, but I can't seem to solve it.
I do see that they're equivalent, but I can't think of a formal proof to show that.

Thanks.

Comment: By equivalent do you mean equal?

Comment: Yes, I meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{2,3\}, C = \{3,4,5\}$. Then $A \Delta (B \cap C) = \{1,2,3\}$ whereas $A \Delta B = \{1,3\}$ and $A \Delta C = \{1,2,3,4,5 \}$. So $(A \Delta B) \cap (A \Delta C) = \{1,3\} \neq A \Delta (B \cap C).$

Comment: I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that if  x∈A and  x∉(B∩C) then it's neither in B nor in C? Wouldn't it just mean that it's isn't in their intersection?

Comment: You're right, there was a mistake. Take a look at the example.

Comment: Okay now I understand, thanks :) They're not equal but I've managed to prove that (AΔB)∩(AΔC) is a subset of AΔ(B∩C), so it works only one side and not equal

Comment: Very good, thanks for the comment anyway.